# Load div when i open the page

Tags: html

Good Morning comunity, im really new on this coding so iam sorry if this question is too noob.

I want a DIV PA load automatically a php file when i open the web page, please i dont want to load with any interval, just load instant when open web.

I tried this code but im sure it is not working

```
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function)()
{
    $('#apDiv3').load('xFile.php');
}
);
</script>
```

Thank you in advance for your time!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the result with a debugger like Firefox's Firebug? Check the network communication to see if the ajax request was completed successfully.

Also, you can try to a callback function to see if the code was executed successfully:

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html", function() {
alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

if you don't get the expected output, it might be a problem on the server-side.

Also... are you sure you are using this exact code? I don't think you should close the brackets after `function`

```
$(document).ready(function)
```

this is how you do it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
....
```

Comment: Thank you Mr Marcelo!! i closed the brackets withow notice!!
I didnt see it. Thank you again!
My regards!